# Limiting API request in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a DRF coupon system for course purchases, how can I limit the coupon validity on the basis of number of user used it or some specific time span.

For ex. only first 50 users can use the code or it will be valid only for next week.

I've read a bit of throttling but if I am not wrong it only limits on the basis of rate Any reference will be really helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: Rather than limiting the API, why not just `save` the number of coupons used in some variable/in database,ie, if you are limiting using numbers. But if you are limiting using date then `timedelta` is your best bet.

Comment: @RevTpark So basically like store number of coupon and decrement it after each request in case of limiting by user and just delete the coupon after the time period in case of limiting using timedelta , is that right ?

Comment: Yes correct. Maybe increment/decrement after a successful request only

Comment: Limiting the API request would be a bad idea in your scenario. Once the coupon is successfully used, you keep a track of the usage number in the database by saving the number and incrementing it after further use. When the number reaches 50, you should restrict the operation dynamically. Deleting the coupon is NOT needed either.